# Logging SQL in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to log SQL statements in Entity Framework Core version 6.0.1, however when I attempt the following, I do not get access to the `Log` property in Visual Studio 2022 autocomplete, and I get a compilation error in my code if I write it manually:

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
}
```

I am using version 6.0.x as the documentation indicates is required to use this feature:

[image]

What has me really confused is that if I look at the `DatabaseFacade` [class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-6.0), which Visual Studio indicates is the type of the `Database` property, I cannot find the `Log` property.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I did, unfortunately the admin deleted the answer.